# Problems with positioning to-do list elements

Tags: html, css

I'm building a React.js to-do list that should look like the one on this picture: [image: Example]

This is what I currently have: [image: My app]

I've tried to position elements with float parameter but it isn't working.

Can you please explain to me what is a mistake and help to fix it? I've added the code below:

**listItem.js:**

```
return (
          <li className='list-item' onClick={() => {this.props.setActiveComment(); this.props.toggleHidden()}}>
            <h3>{this.props.item.title}</h3>
            <span>{this.props.item.commentsCount}</span>
            <button onClick={(event) => this.props.removeItem(this.props.id)}>Delete</button>
          </li>
```

**listItem.css:**

```
.list-item {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
.list-item button {
    width: 97px;
    height: 34px;
    border: 2px solid #FF3159;
    color: #FF3159;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    line-height: inherit;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    overflow: visible;
    text-transform: none;
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
}
.list-item button:hover {
    background: #f44336;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.list-item h3 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

.list-item span {
    width: 39px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #27CCC0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**App.js:**

```
<div className='list-wrapper'>
            <h1>Items</h1>
            <ListInput inputText='' addItem={this.addItem}/>
            <ul>
              {
                this.state.items.map((item) => 
                (<ListItem 
                    item={item} 
                    key={item.id} 
                    id={item.id} 
                    removeItem={this.removeItem} 
                    setActiveComment={() => this.setState({ activeItem: item })} 
                    toggleHidden={() => this.setState({ isHidden: false })}
                  />
                ))
              }
            </ul>
          </div>
```

**App.css:**

```
.list-wrapper {
  margin: 40px 40px 20px 270px;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
  border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.list-wrapper h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the items have stacked as they have in your second picture is due to the use of floats.

Using floats removes an item from the normal document flow causing the parent element to have a height of only the non floated items it contains. In this case a `<span>` element.

If the floated elements parent contained nothing but floated elements, the height of it would literally collapse to nothing. This isn't always obvious if the parent doesn't contain any visually noticeable background, but it is important to be aware of.

If you interested in learning more about floats and the gotcha's, Chris Coyier has a great resource over at CSS Tricks : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

I have created a JS fiddle below and added a few float clears which was the quickest way to achieve the layout from the fist picture you posted. See below :

https://jsfiddle.net/3hs6gxco/1/

While this will work, it may not be the best way to do it. I see you have a class called `flex-container` declared but haven't used it in the example you posted.

Here is another example that uses flexbox a little more, but in all, uses less CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/a76ux58y/

Hope this helps.